# How to convert BufferedImage to javaxt.io.Image?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, skew

I need to skew an image using `image.setCorners()` which can be done using JavaXT library.
However I have the image in `BufferedImage` form and not a saved file.

So how do I convert a `BufferedImage` to a `javaxt.io.Image` so that I can perform the skew operation over it.

Here is the code I am using to skew the image:

```
javaxt.io.Image image = new javaxt.io.Image("image1.jpg");

System.out.println(image.getWidth() + "x" + image.getHeight());
int width = image.getWidth();
int height = image.getHeight();
image.setCorners(0, 0,             //UL
                 width, 10,        //UR
                 width, height-10, //LR
                 0, height);       //LL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The[`javaxt.io.Image`](http://www.javaxt.com/documentation/?jar=javaxt-core.jar&class=Image&package=javaxt.io) class has a constructor like:

```
public Image(java.awt.image.BufferedImage bufferedImage)
```

so you can do:

```
javaxt.io.Image image = new javaxt.io.Image(bufferedImage);
```